# Java Plugin Web after install JDK

Tags: java, ubuntu, browser, java-6

I have installed the jdk, I can compile files .java and execute any java command in the command line, but I when try view an applet in the browser this not work.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

I use ubuntu, JDK6 and chrome (or firefox). The JAVA_HOME point the jdk folder.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: I think this should be asked on the superuser site http://superuser.com/ not SO and you should mention what browser you are using.

Comment: In any browser not work, I use Chrome or firefox generally

Comment: What's diference between this site and superuser.com?

Comment: Do 32bit/64bit match between browser and JDK (=plugin inside it)?

Comment: My OS is 64bit and chrome's version is 64bit